# Docker redis unauthorised access

Tags: docker, security, docker-compose, redis

Digital Ocean advises me Redis may be unintentionally exposing data or misconfigured to allow unauthorised access.

A telnet command confirms this.

However, I need to allow my docker container on the same network to access Redis; enabling external access seems to be the only way!

How can I configure my docker-compose to allow access between the 2 containers securely:

```
version: '2'

services:

  redis:
    networks:
      - youtube
    image: redis
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    expose:
      - "6379"
    container_name: youtube_cache
    command: sh -c 'redis-server --bind 0.0.0.0'
    restart: always

  node:
    tty: true # Enables debugging capabilities when attached to this container.
    image: 'docker.io/bitnami/node:12-debian-10'
    command: sh -c 'npm install && npm rebuild && node app'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    links:
      - redis
    environment:
      - REDIS_URL=redis://youtube_cache
    container_name: youtube_scraper
    networks:
      - youtube
    restart: always

networks:
  youtube:
    external: true
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is your docker-compose file is configured to expose the port 6379 of your *youtube_cache* container to the *youtube* network, which happens to be `external`.
To solve this, you need to:

1. stop exposing the port through `ports` (`expose` is informative only);
2. do not attach *youtube_cache* do the `external` network but just leave it on the default (internal) network docker-compose automatically creates;
3. add the *youtube_scraper* container to that default network as well, so that it can communicate with the first one.

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: youtube_cache
    command: sh -c 'redis-server --bind 0.0.0.0'
    restart: always

  node:
    tty: true # Enables debugging capabilities when attached to this container.
    image: 'docker.io/bitnami/node:12-debian-10'
    command: sh -c 'npm install && npm rebuild && node app'
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    links:
      - redis
    environment:
      - REDIS_URL=redis://youtube_cache
    container_name: youtube_scraper
    networks:
      - youtube
      - default
    restart: always

networks:
  youtube:
    external: true
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I presume 'default' isn't the actual name required for the internal network or does docker-compose pick that up as a keyword to specify that?

Comment: My pleasure. `default` is the actual network name - see https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#configure-the-default-network

Comment: @MikeThrussell please consider accepting this answer if it solved your issue. ;)